# Orchard Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, orchardcms

Currently we have a few products defined in Orchard.
We managed do display these products by using a query in combination with projection.
I executed the same steps as described in this tutorial, [Defining and rendering the ProductCatalog Content Type](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5)

There is also a menu to navigate inside products catalog. When selecting category, the full page is refreshed. How can we implement a ajax request each time user select a product category in menu?

Here i will show you an example of the screen:
[image: Products Overview]

Comment: Provide more information if you want more accurate answers. But you would need to implement a Controller and a Route to hook this.

Comment: Basically, i have followed this tutorial [link](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5). I have also updated my original question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet is to do something along those lines:

- Create a module with a custom ApiController
- Write an alternate for your category navigation in which you send an ajax request to your controller
- Use IContentManager in your controller to query for your products and return them as a json result
- Update your page from your result